# Logging to JavaScript console from AppDelegate.m with React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is it possible to put logging statements into `AppDelegate.m` which will print out in the Chrome JavaScript debugger console when using React Native?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

RCTLog(@"Some information");
```